# I have an issue in updating files in server using Filezilla

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, filezilla

My client gave me FTP Connection  details, To upload my asp.net site. but when I updating my files using filezilla client, Files are updating but, Application in the browser showing Old results (Before update). only javascript and css files are coming properly

Is there  any option to resolve this? and I don't have remote desktop connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upload an `App_Offline.htm` to your root directory when you make such changes. This shows an offline message to users while you make the changes.

Refer: [ScottGu's Blog about App_Offline.htm](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx)

> The way app_offline.htm works is that you place this file in the root
>   of the application.  When ASP.NET sees it, it will shut-down the
>   app-domain for the application (and not restart it for requests) and
>   instead send back the contents of the app_offline.htm file in response
>   to all new dynamic requests for the application.  When you are done
>   updating the site, just delete the file and it will come back online.

These will cause your replaced dlls to be used, show a graceful message while you make the changes and doesn't require a remote desktop connection.